# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE not defined when building Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codeandchaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/sphinx-autodoc-tutorial-for-dummies/) in order to generate documentation for my Django project.

I've added `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), '..'))` to the `conf.py` file within my documentation directory.

But running `make html` keeps giving me errors like this:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

My project is running fine, so I'm not sure where I'm supposed to call `settings.configure()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Directory Structure**

Basing on a vanilla install with the following directory structure here are the steps that should work. The directory structure may be different as long as the path in `conf.py` is set correctly.

```
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── index.rst
└── myproj
    ├── anapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── myproj
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

**Sphinx Configuration**

`conf.py` needs a few settings so that `autodoc` is able to bootstrap the Django app:

```
# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), '../../myproj'))    # <•• 1

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproj.settings'                  # <•• 2

import django
django.setup()                                                            # <•• 3
```

**1 ⇒** appending the Django project directory (the one with `manage.py`) to the Python path, which is necessary for 2 and for resolving `autodoc` directives in the `.rst` files.

**2 ⇒** setting an env variable with the location of the settings module. This example is based on a vanilla django-admin setup. If you are using a more sophisticated settings structure (e.g. `dev`, `staging`, `production` settings extending from some base settings) just update the path, e.g. `myproj.settings.dev`.

**3 ⇒** finally calling [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) is necessary to populate Django's application registry, which Sphinx needs in order to generate the docs from an intact Django setup.

Everything should be in place now for `$ make html` to work with `autodoc`.

Comment: Ahh... made those changes to my `conf.py` and moved my docs folder outside of myproject and now it works! Thanks!